# No puedo establecer id de ImageViewer

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-imageview, navigation-drawer

Estoy introduciendo una imagen en un CardView para usarlo en un RecyclerView que se encuentra en un fragment.

Si introduzco el ImageView y borro el id, la aplicación funciona correctamente y se me muestra el listado de CardView dentro del RecyclerView

El problema ocurre al ponerle un id a los ImageView, en ese caso da este error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.twittor, PID: 16374
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.twittor/com.example.twittor.PrincipalActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ID does not reference a View inside this Activity
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ID does not reference a View inside this Activity
        at android.app.Activity.requireViewById(Activity.java:3375)
        at androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.requireViewById(ActivityCompat.java:363)
        at androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController(Navigation.java:58)
        at com.example.twittor.PrincipalActivity.onCreate(PrincipalActivity.java:54)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

El PrincipalActivity es el NavigationDrawer que genera automáticamente Android Studio:

```
package com.example.twittor;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class PrincipalActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    private RecyclerView listaTwoots;
    private NavigationView navigationview;
    private TextView userName, userMail;
    private String username, usermail;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);


        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

        setUserData(navigationView);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.principal, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    private void setUserData(NavigationView navigationView){
        View header=navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

        username = getIntent().getStringExtra("userName");
        usermail = getIntent().getStringExtra("userMail");

        userName = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.userName);
        userMail = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.userMail);

        userName.setText(username);
        userMail.setText(usermail);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Establecido "+username+" y "+usermail, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Lo único que se le añade a este java es el método de setUserData, el cual establece el nombre de usuario y correo que aparece en la información del usuario del menú lateral

Answer (score 0):

Según el log, el error es que no se pudo encontrar ninguna `View` con el id `nav_host_fragment`. Sin ver el xml no puedo decirte a que se debe pero puedo sugerirte otra forma de obtener el `NavController`.

Primero asegurate de que el `NavHostFragment` sea un `FragmentContainerView` y no un simple `Fragment`. Debería verse así:

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
```

Luego reemplaza esta línea

```
NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
```

por estas

```
NavHostFragment navHostFragment =
    (NavHostFragment) supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);
NavController navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();
```

Si después de eso sigue apareciendo el mismo error significa que, por algún extraño motivo, el layout del `Fragment` definido en tu `NavGraph` como startDestination está impidiendo que el `NavHostFragment` sea encontrado. Una solución es inflar ese fragment **después** de haber encontrado el navHost. Para eso remueve este atributo xml `app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"` y agrega a tu código la siguiente línea

```
navController.setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph);
```

**PD**: Te recomiendo realizar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) que te explicará el funcionamiento básico de este sitio y también leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) porque  es muy difícil que consigas ayuda haciendo preguntas de tan baja calidad.

Comment: Gracias, lo intentaré, lo que no encuentro es la relación entre el error y la asignación del id del ImageView

Comment: He probado el primer método que me has comentado, recibo el siguiente error: `Activity com.example.twittor.PrincipalActivity@17e933e does not have a NavController set on 2131296539`

Comment: el navHost lo tienes en el archivo content_main.xml pero no veo que lo estés incluyendo en tu activity principal. De hecho no entiendo por qué está en un archivo aparte. En general la app no está muy bien hecha. Te recomiendo hacer el [curso oficial de android](https://developer.android.com/courses/android-basics-kotlin/course) o por lo menos leer un poco sobre arquitectura

Comment: Nu sé, todo lo que son las cosas de navegación me las ha creado Android Studio automáticamente al hacer una actividad Navigation Drawer, gracias por la recomendación del curso

Comment: Ok, prueba agregar esta línea en el layout de tu activity principal `<include layout="@layout/content_main"/>`

Comment: o mejor elimina el archivo y copia solamente el navHost

Comment: AL final parece ser que el proyecto fallaba por cosas más profundas del Android Studio, ahora estoy reescribiendo todo el proyecto (sin cambiar de máquina) a ver si no da problemas de incompatibilidad de versiones, te cuento si así lo consigo solucionar